# Unity Sceneview quality worse than Gameview

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

So, basically I am trying to use URP for my project right now. However, i just noticed that the Scene View quality is rendering worse than Game View. I tryied to modified the settings in Project settings, but looks like nothings works. does anyone have this problem before that can give me some suggestion? all the question answer that I found online is about the otherwise. Here is the Image:
[GameView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3VWR.png)
[SceneView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neuHU.png)
As you can see the Scene View is more pixelated.
Thanks a lot for anyone that can give me an advise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small camera icon in the top right corner of the scene tab. There you can activate the anti-aliasing for the scene view camera.